# Check if some word exists using Word dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, ms-word, vsto, spell-checking

I'm developing a Word 2010 AddIn using C# and VSTO.
I wanted to know if I can check some word exists in the Word's dictionary?

I find this `var dict = Application.CustomDictionaries.ActiveCustomDictionary;`
but I don't know how can I use it to check if some word exists.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the dictionary file by hand, and check whether the word exists in the list.

Try this:

```
string[] words = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CustomDictionaries[1].Path, Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CustomDictionaries[1].Name));

bool wordExists = words.Contains("yourWord");
```

**NOTE:**

Your example reads the custom dictionary, not the Word internal dictionary. As far as I know it is not possible to read the default dictionary.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, i tried it and i'm getting "unauthorizedaccessexception" when i'm trying to read the file. How can i overcome this?

Comment: @user3323203: what is the path of the dictionary. Do you have access to it?

Comment: The path is "AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UProof" and i have access to it.

Comment: @user3323203: Sorry, missed that one. The `Path` only contains the directory, the `Name` the actual file name.

Comment: Sorry, i thought it work, but i made a mistake, i wanted to get word's dictionary and not the custom dictionary. (want to take some word and check if it exist in the language)

Comment: @user332303: as mentioned in the note in my answer this is not possible. This code only works for the custom dictionary. Use an online dictionary service if you want to check all words.